# Changing the font used by \SetPaperName in 'newsletter' package

Tags: fonts, macros, titles

I'm trying to change the font of the `newspaper` template which you can find [here](https://fr.overleaf.com/latex/templates/newspaper-slash-news-letter-template/wjxxhkxdjxhw) and which is described [there](http://mirror.hmc.edu/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/newspaper/newspaper.pdf).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{microtype}

\usepackage{newspaper}


\date{\today}
\currentvolume{1}
\currentissue{1}

\SetPaperName{La F des 13 régions}
\SetPaperName{\fontfamily{phv}\selectfont{\huge{\bfseries{La F des 13 régions}}}} % I tried this


\SetPaperLocation{}
\SetPaperSlogan{Sous la direction de L. Carroué}
\SetPaperPrice{Me}

%%%%%%%%%  Front matter   %%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

It changed the size of Committee Time but not the font :

[image]

Comment: Which font do you want to use?

Comment: @Bernard Oh, something simple. Why not the one provided by default Latex for titles ?

Comment: There is no font specified in your link. So it seems to use the default `Computer Modern` (or `Latin Modern` if you compile with xelatex).

Comment: @Bernard I'm compiling on Overleaf

Comment: @Bernard Is there any chance to change it ? :)

Comment: Sorry for the delay – the packaage wasn't installed on my system, and I hadn't much time. I propose a solution based on `xpatch`, but wouldn't it be simpler to customise `\maketitle` from scratch, with the help of the  `titling` package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package sets the font encoding for the paper name to LYG. Change it to T1.

Also note that `\huge` and `\bfseries` *don't* take arguments.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{microtype}

\usepackage{newspaper}

\date{\today}
\currentvolume{1}
\currentissue{1}

\SetPaperName{%
  \fontencoding{T1}\fontfamily{phv}\fontsize{36}{0}\bfseries
  La F des 13 régions%
}
\SetPaperLocation{}
\SetPaperSlogan{Sous la direction de L. Carroué}
\SetPaperPrice{Me}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution with `xpatch` and `moresize`:

```
\documentclass[french]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{moresize}

\usepackage{newspaper}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\date{\today}
\currentvolume{1}
\currentissue{1}

\SetPaperName{La F des 13 régions}

\SetPaperLocation{}
\SetPaperSlogan{Sous la direction de L. Carroué}
\SetPaperPrice{Me}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\maketitle}{%
\textgoth{\HUGE\usefont{LYG}{bigygoth}{m}{n} \@papername}}%
{\textbf{\sffamily\huge \@papername}}%
{}{}
\makeatother
%%%%%%%%% Front matter %%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]